# How can I pass parameter to (Get-PnPUser | ? Email -eq ($SPUserEmail));

Tags: powershell, error, administration, pnp-powershell, pnp

I have the following PnP PowerShell script:

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=$DBServer;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=$DBName")                        
$conn.Open();                        
$query = $Query                        
$dap = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($query,$conn);                        
$dt = new-object System.Data.DataTable;                        
$null = $dap.Fill($dt)  
      foreach($r in $dt.Rows )   {                         
$SPUserEmail = $r["email_address"];
$SPuser = (Get-PnPUser | ? Email -eq ($SPUserEmail));}
```

but I always get this error:

```
The specified user  could not be found.
```

but if I type the email address manually I get the user details:

```
$SPuser = (Get-PnPUser | ? Email -eq test@test.com);
```

although when I do `Write-Host $SPUserEmail` I will get `test@test.com`

So what could be the reason?

Comment: Is `$SPUserEmail` holding string/text value? Can you try running script after removing `( )` around `$SPUserEmail`? Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @GaneshSanap removing the `()` did not change any thing

Answer (score 0):

It's because `$SPUserEmail` holds a object, and the email is a property. `Get-PnpUser` expects a string value.

**PropertyName** is the property name found in the object.

To get only the value out of the object, either select it when setting the variable:

```
$SPUserEmail = $r["email_address"] | Select-Object PropertyName -ExpandProperty PropertyName
```

Or by expanding the property value you need:

```
(Get-PnPUser | Where-Object Email -eq ($SPUserEmail.PropertyName))
```

Comment: so what i need to define for the PropertyName  ?

Comment: also when i tried `$r["email_address"].TypeOf()` i will get the following                    `IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object` so seems it is a string

Comment: By printing $r["email_address"] it should print the propertyname + the value.

Comment: i think the problem is when calling the function i opened another question @ https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305623/calling-get-pnpuser-email-eq-email-from-another-function-is-not-working